# How I can specify the absolute position of the image?

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can I specify the absolute position of the image when export a power point using apache poi ?

```
File img = new File("/image/","hoge.png");
byte[] data;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(img);
data = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
XSLFPictureData pictureIndex = ppt.addPicture(data,PictureData.PictureType.PNG)
XSLFPictureShape shape = slide1.createPicture(pictureIndex);
```

Comment: I close this one as a duplicate then, have a nice day ;)

Comment: oh...
I wanna comment this question, but I can't comment.
becouse I have not reached the reputation of 50 yet.